# PHP Search Feature not printing results

Tags: php

This is my code :

```
if(isset($_GET['search'])) {

    $search_value= $_GET['searchbox'];
    echo "Search results for $search_value";
    print "<br><br>";    

    $query="
        SELECT idemp,sn 
        FROM employee 
        WHERE idemp like '%search_value%' 
            OR sn like '%search_value%'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc($query)) {

            $idemp=$row->idemp;
            $sn=$row->sn;

            echo $row['$idemp'];
            echo $row['$sn'];
        }
    } 
};
```

it didn't return matching result even if there is an equivalent in the database... help tnx...

Answer (score 0):

Your'e not including the variable in the query, you're including only its name (without the $?).

```
$query="SELECT idemp,sn FROM employee 
WHERE idemp like '%$search_value%' OR
sn like '%$search_value%'";
```

Since you're using mysqli, it would be better to bind the values either way, since it will normalize the input and prevent injection. Here's an example:

```
$conn->prepare("SELECT idemp,sn FROM employee 
WHERE idemp like ? OR
sn like ?");
$conn->bind_params('ss', $search_value, $search_value);
$conn->execute(); // <-- returns the query results
```

Comment: <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "auth";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "auth");
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

Comment: this is my connection